# The type or namespace name 'Firebase' could not be found in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, firebase, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, namespaces

Why I am always getting the following error, although the package "Xamarin.Firebase.Auth" is already added in my Android Projekt.

Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Firebase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Testing)

Screenshot:
[image]

Any ideas why this might be occurring?
I am using:

Visual Studio 2019
Version 8.8.10 (build 2)

In my previous Project everything worked fine....
See the following screenshot.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the nuget is added to your **Android** project, but `MainPage` is part of your **Forms** project

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the answer, but could you please clarify a little bit or any solution. I am totally stucked.

Comment: install the nuget package in the Forms project

Comment: @jason Could be this a new update? It has been a long time that I haven't worked with Visual Studio, but as long as I know, it was enough to add any packages in Android or iOS project and then access it in everywhere in your project.  SEE SCREENSHOT

Comment: You could try to add the nuget in Forms project as Jason said.